# what does 'smt' mean, why is 'smt' often used as a prefix of a database name?

Tags: sql, database, computer-science, naming

I find that many databases are named with a prefix 'smt_' in industry, for example, 'smt_customer_profile', what dose 'smt' mean? Is there any special meaning in this prefix?

I have asked my supervisor about this question, getting the answer that the reason behind this naming is very geek style, which really invokes my curiosity! So I tried to google it, some interpretations are like:

- satisfiability modulo theories (SMT)
- Simultaneous multithreading
- Small Mini-Tower

all seemingly not the right answer...

So does anybody know about this, many thanks!!!

Comment: Never heard of it <something> master table? smart? I dunno.

Comment: Me neither. This is an irrelevant question I must say, maybe more relevant over at https://dba.stackexchange.com but I doubt it. Voting to close

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about some (possible) naming standard for databases

Comment: You have to ask the person who created the database.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen this in the industry myself, but the best guess would be `Subscription Management Tool`, this is what I found SMT in relation to databases:

https://www.suse.com/documentation/smt11/book_yep/data/book_yep.html

It's part of SUSE Linux operating system

Answer (score 0):

What the actual meaning of smt is could be anything.  This falls into a class of naming conventions called Hungarian notation -- that is a prefix that defines the "type" or "class" of an object.

Sometimes this was literally the type -- in other cases it might be the equivilant to a modern module (before object oriented programming).

In any case it is very old fashioned and has been replaced with name spaces or schemas for most things.